Calculate Total Profit and Loss (PnL) using Pandas Dataframe
I have this pandas dataframe where close are the close prices and entry price is the close price where position was opened. When position is closed, the entry price will turn to NaN again until another position was open again.
Now I want to find the PnL of the whole strategy. It is kind of cumulative summation but not really since within the trading position, I do not want the PnL to be add up. So I am a bit confused.
Assume only 1 quantity is bought at any point of time for this backtesting.
    close  entry_prices
0      98           NaN
1     101         101.0
2     106         101.0
3     107         101.0
4     110         101.0
5     111         101.0
6     120           NaN
7     123           NaN
8     124           NaN
9     123         123.0
10    122         123.0
11    123         123.0
12    120         123.0
13    121           NaN
14    125           NaN

I tried this but the PNL kind of messed up between the trading position
df['pnl'] = np.where(df['entry_prices'].shift() == df['entry_prices'], df['close'] - df['entry_prices'], 0)

# Initialize strategy_pnl column
df['strategy_pnl'] = np.nan

# Calculate the cumulative sum of total P&L regardless of trading positions
cumulative_pnl = 0
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    if not np.isnan(row['entry_prices']):
        pnl = row['close'] - row['entry_prices']
        cumulative_pnl += pnl
    df.at[idx, 'strategy_pnl'] = cumulative_pnl

This is the result I want
    close  entry_prices  Total_PNL
0      98           NaN          0
1     101         101.0          0
2     106         101.0          5
3     107         101.0          6
4     110         101.0          9
5     111         101.0         10
6     120           NaN         10
7     123           NaN         10
8     124           NaN         10
9     123         123.0         10
10    122         123.0          9
11    123         123.0          9
12    120         123.0          6
13    121           NaN          6
14    125           NaN          6


In your sample output, why is Total_PNL non-cumulative within the first position but cumulative in the second position?

Since I want a total PnL of the whole trading strategy. The second position has to keep tracking of previous position PnL. Given that the buying quantity, assets are consistent. For this case, I think looping is also essential.

I made a mistake on my desired result. Sorry for the confusion. But i have solved the problem now thanks a lot

If i understand correctly, if you have positive value closing for the day but if its negative considering last day positive value to deduct the loss.
if in that case, below code might help you
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Sample DataFrame
data = {
    'close': [98, 101, 106, 107, 110, 111, 120, 123, 124, 123, 122, 123, 120, 121, 125],
    'entry_prices': [np.nan, 101.0, 101.0, 101.0, 101.0, 101.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 123.0, 123.0, 123.0, 123.0, np.nan, np.nan],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Calculate the difference
df['difference'] = df['close'] - df['entry_prices']

# Initialize variables
prv_day = 0
results = []

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if pd.isna(row['entry_prices']):
        results.append(np.nan)
    else:
        if row['difference'] > 0:
            results.append(row['difference'])
            prv_day = row['difference']
        else:
            if prv_day + row['difference'] > 0:
                results.append(prv_day + row['difference'])
                prv_day += row['difference']
            else:
                results.append(0)
                prv_day = 0

df['result'] = results

# Fill NaN values with the last valid observation
df['result'] = df['result'].fillna(method='ffill')

print(df)


You need to change the line to df['result'] = df['result'].ffill().fillna(0) to get the results the OP requires (ie correct first value in new column).

My understanding of the question is that the first value of entry_prices will always be Nan because this marks the initial trading opening position. Hence my suggestion. In any event your code does not give the expected value as defined by the OP for the first new element.

The first value does not need to be Nan. It is more reasonable to set 0 initially, even without an entry prices existing.

Tested with the code @Deepak provided, almost there. But starting from the second position, the logic won't work as intended. When the difference is greater than 0, the result append the difference directly. It does not keep track on the previous pnl. Try with this data and you will notice that row 10 should be difference + prev pnl = 20 instead of 10. data = {     'close': [98, 101, 106, 107, 110, 111, 120, 123, 124, 123, 133, 123, 120, 121, 125],     'entry_prices': [np.nan, 101.0, 101.0, 101.0, 101.0, 101.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 123.0, 123.0, 123.0, 123.0, np.nan, np.nan], }

df['pos'] = np.where(df['entry_prices'].notnull(), 1, 0)
df.loc[df['entry_prices'].notnull() & ~df['entry_prices'].duplicated(), 'pos'] = 0
df['diff'] = df['close'].diff()
df['ur_pnl'] = (df['diff'] * df['pos']).cumsum()

print(df)

I did it in this way. No loop required. Not sure if this is the best way, but at least result is what I want.
